# I want to cover the whole screen with a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I want to cover the whole screen with a div.

Using an iframe covers everything:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="source.html" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999;">
```

But I want to do this with a div:

```
<div id="lessonContents" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999;">
```

I am using Reveal.js with the sky.css theme. For some reason, the elements outside of the div are visible even though the sky.css theme has a blue background.

For example, this is a picture of a link that should be covered up by the div. As you can see the background is blue as a result of sky.css theme:

[image]

How can I cover everything with the div?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `position: absolute` in conjunction with `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`.

```css
#full_page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="full_page"></div>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y2ps3kms/).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use `vw` and `vh`, which is viewport width and viewport height respectively. This will ensure the entirely of the viewport is covered.

You can read more about that in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

```
<div id="lessonContents" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100vw; height:100vh; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999;>
```

I would also ensure your `lessonContents` div has a background to ensure all content is hidden.

Comment: Using vw and vh didn't work. If I add a background to the div it does cover everything up but the sky.css theme already has a backgound. So I guess I have to add one for the div also?

Comment: Sorry my code was slightly incorrect, just amended. (Just incase you copied my snippet)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't copy it and I noticed that you used vh twice. In my code, I tried vw and vh.

Comment: Ah, it was meant to be `position: absolute`

Answer (score 1):

You can set "position:absolute" to the your cover div.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
}
.cover {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <p>Back to course</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a background-color to your div's styles, for example `background-color: #fff;`

Otherwise it will be transparent, which is the reason why you see the other elements behind it.

Comment: I tried this but then I lose the effect of the sky.css blue background. "background-color: #f7fbfc;" I guess I have to add this to the div also?

Comment: But of course you loose the background color of the elements behind that. You either have a background color which covers the stuff behind it, or the background is transparent, which lets you see the contents of the elements behind your DIV. If that background is all you are missing, just add `background-color: #f7fbfc;` to your `styles` attribute, as you wrote yourself.

Comment: It seems weird that the div is transparent since it is filled with content. Anyway, you are right about the background color. What I did instead was <style> section{ z-index:999; } </style> because each slide in Reveal.js is a section.